# Add a picture/thumbnail in a 3d projection matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, legend

In matplotlib, does anyone know how to add a picture or thumbnail to a 3d-projection plot outside of the margin of the figure? The thumbnail is a png/jpeg image from a file.

I'm thinking of something analogous to this example, but with a picture:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
r = z**2 + 1
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/watermark_image.html). Alternatively, you can add a new axes to the corner of the figure to plot your image to.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick!